# Change updatePeriodMillis from activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I change paramentr updatePeriodMillis or deny renewal of the widget's Activity? It is necessary that you could disable the update from the application settings.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change paramentr updatePeriodMillis

You cannot change `updatePeriodMillis` -- resources are read-only at runtime.

> or deny renewal of the widget's Activity?

It is unclear what you mean by this.

> It is necessary that you could disable the update from the application settings.

Either:

1. Do not use `updatePeriodMillis`, but handle updates yourself using `AlarmManager`, which you can then completely control yourself, or
2. In `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider`, check your `SharedPreferences` (or wherever you are storing your "settings"), and if they indicate that updates are disabled, simply return without doing anything